# How do I outline certain blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying a flying platform that follows the player with

```
/execute @p ~ ~-1 ~ fill ~-1 ~ ~-1 ~1 ~ ~1 glass 0 replace air
```

and then deleting the blocks with

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-2 ~-2 ~-2 ~2 ~ ~2 air 0 outline glass 0
```

However, it destroys all the surrounding blocks. I would like to know if there's a way to make it so that it wouldn't destroy other blocks.

Comment: Search for "fill" in the Minecraft wiki. In general search before asking.

Comment: I did but it doesnt answer my question

Comment: Why not? It says it right there: `fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <block> <dataValue|state> replace [replaceTileName] [replaceDataValue]` Please specify what you don't understand about it.

Comment: im not trying to replace, im trying to outline

Comment: I think I get now what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

That command doesn't exist in the form you're imagining it. There is a way to outline, but it  doesn't make a rectangle in 2D and it isn't applicable to only certain blocks. You're thinking about two different syntaxes for `/fill`, but they can't be mixed. When in doubt, always look at [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill), it tells you everything you need.

In your case, you should just put the command that replaces the glass with air first, then make the new platform immediately.